# Traverse is undefined and performance lagging THREE.js Clock? *although it works*

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

It seems to be doing what it is supposed to be doing -- traversing the scene and updating the meshes -- however, it's not listing all my meshes in the scene -- although they are being rendered (bizarre).  It's also giving me error messages saying it can't traverse the scene (even though it is and its working).  My performance is garbage.  I assume I am just approaching this wrong.  Any suggestions?

Here is the link to the running sample.
http://codepen.io/wpdildine/pen/ZGprWp

```
function checkSec(prevSec){
    var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff9000 } ); 
    var curTime = new Date();

    if (prevSec != curTime.getSeconds() || prevSec == null){
        scene.traverse(function(children){
            if (children instanceof THREE.Mesh && children.name == 'sec'){
                scene.remove(children)    
            }
        });           
        prevSec = curTime.getSeconds();
        prevSec = setZeros(prevSec);
        var secGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(":" + prevSec, {size:5, height:1});
        var sec = new THREE.Mesh( secGeometry, mat);
        sec.name = 'sec';
        sec.position.set(10,0,0);
        scene.add(sec);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to traverse the scene at all if you make the variables `hour`, `min` and `sec` global variables. Then you would just have to call:

```
scene.remove( hour );
```

just before you add the new `hour` mesh. Same for `min` and `sec`.

Also you should not have `.shadowMapEnabled` when you are not rendering shadows.

Comment: I made adjustments according to your specs and everything seems to work (I can't put it in an variable as it needs to be in an array for me to remove it).   However, I get random crashes and I can't figure out why its devouring so many resources...

Comment: which variable has to be an array?

Comment: Still having performance issues...  I added used the .dispose function to do some garbage clean up but it still seems to crash...

Comment: I updated the codepen --  it seems to be work better but after a period of time I get a crash.

Comment: OK. You are creating the TextGeometry in each frame. But all you have to do is create the 10 numbers beforehand and then just use them whn you need them.

Comment: That would solve the issue --  It does look like from my logs my gpu is crashing?  You wouldn't happen to have any idea why so I can avoid this in the future?

Comment: increased load. that's what we have been trying to avoid.

Comment: Got it... try and avoid generating new meshes/geometries in the animation function.

Comment: also this is a good read: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/